# Is there a way to get XML::Twig to understand a UTF-16-encoded XML file?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Is there a way to get [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) to understand a UTF-16-encoded XML file?

The code to read the file is what was stated in the tutorials:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

# ...

my $twig=XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => { ... },
  prety_print => 'indented',
  keep_encoding => 1,
};

# ...

$twig->parsefile('myXmlFile.xml');  # <= line 71
```

Error is:

```
error parsing tag '<RIBBON>' at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/XML/Parser/Expat.pm line 470
 at ../../cv32/res/convert-xml-string2.pl line 71
 at ../../cv32/res/convert-xml-string2.pl line 71
```

The XML starts off like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Changing my opening code as Borodin suggests, it still doesn't work:

```
# parse the XML file
open(my $xmlIn, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', $xmlFile) or die "Couldn't open xml file '$xmlFile'. $!";
$twig->parse($xmlIn); # <= line 72
```

The error becomes:

```
encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect at line 1, column 30, byte 30 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/XML/Parser.pm line 187
 at ../../cv32/res/convert-xml-string2.pl line 72
```

Comment: does the file have the encoding declared (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`) or a byte order mark at the beginning?

Comment: @ysth, Both are done.

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you have written, and describe how it isn't working for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the XML parser used by XML::Twig (XML::Parser) doesn't support
UTF-16. You need to convert the XML document to a supported encoding (e.g. UTF-8) first.

For example,

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $xml;
{
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die $!;
   local $/;
   $xml = <$fh>;
}

{
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string($xml);
   $doc->setEncoding('UTF-8');
   $xml = $doc->toString();
}

$twig->parse($xml);
```

A lighter solution would be to detect/expect UTF-16, decode the document (using Encode's `decode`), use a regex to adjust the encoding declaration, then encoding the document (using Encodes `encode`).

Comment: I like that lighter solution.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Or, you could avoid using a slow parser that can't even handle your XML.

Comment: I just picked one of the XML libs at somewhat random.  I started with XML::Parse, but found it too clunky and hard to use.  Someone mentioned XML::Twig and I went with it.  Not going to move over to another at the moment, but I take it you prefer XML::LibXML?

Comment: XML::Twig is a very good at some things. One of those is cases where you don't want to load the entire XML file into memory at once. Otherwise, XML::LibXML is a top notch library.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, and you don't show an example of the Perl code that *isn't* working for you. So I have had to make a lot of guesses and am really working in the dark; but I hope that this helps.

[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) subclasses [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser), which provides the `parse` method. The documentation says this

```
parse(SOURCE [, OPT => OPT_VALUE [...]])
    The SOURCE parameter should either be a string containing the whole
    XML document, or it should be an open IO::Handle.
```

That means you can call `open` on your own terms, and pass the file handle to the `XML::Twig->parse` method. Your code should look something like this

```
my $file_name = 'my_file.xml';

open my $xml_fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', $file_name
    or die qq{Unable to open "$file_name" for input: $!};

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse($xml_fh);
```

Comment: Ah, ic.  Didn't see that. The CPAN docs are crappy as there are a bunch of dead links in it, so I gave up looking at the docs. :(  I've only been using `parsefile()`.

Comment: @Adrian: Each module's documentation is usually [*Pod markup*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html). It is part of the module's Perl source, and its quality depends entirely on the diligence of the author: it is nothing to do with the CPAN itself. I am sure that you will forgive others' documentation failures, given the inadequacies of your own question.

Comment: I'm tired, and I couldn't navigate the docs.  If you want to swat me for that, go ahead.  I also didn't know if there was any way other than the way I did found in the docs I could read and is why I made a simple question with just a sentence.  If I had known there was some other way, I would have given more info.  BTW, your suggestion, though it *sounded* reasonable, didn't work. I suppose you didn't test your work prior to posting it.  So we all have our failures and life's full of heart breaks.  Yada, yada, yada...

Comment: @Adrian: Please read what I said. Your question is below par but I answered it, and that could have been the end of things. But you decided to take a shot at the documentation, with *"The CPAN docs are crappy . . ."*. So I pointed out that your own writing wasn't so great either. I didn't test my suggestion because sample UTF-16 XML data isn't the easiest thing to find, and I thought I could leave that to you. If you want more help then you will have to describe the problem better than *"didn't work"*

Comment: You're right. I should have said "the docs I found on the CPAN site are crappy as they have broken links" as that mitigates somewhat CPAN's responsibility for the documentation being sub par.  Is that what you are asking for?  I'll try and be more precise in the future.  I also wrote the explanation as to what didn't work into my original question.